# Powershell script works locally but not under solarwinds SAM component

Tags: powershell, solarwinds-orion

Below is the script which works locally under powershell ISE. But same under SAM Component ie Windows powershell monitor not working

Script checks for doc file under path1 and if exist. It takes copy of the file from  path1 and move to Path2 by renaming with timestamp.

```
$directory = 'path1'
$filter = '*.doc'
$msg = ' '
$com = ","
$count = 0
$stamp = Get-Date -F yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm
Get-ChildItem -Path $directory -Filter $filter | Foreach-Object {
$msg = $msg + $com + $_.FullName
$dest = "path1" + $_.Name
$newName = "path1" + "$($_.BaseName)_$stamp$($_.Extension)"
Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $newName
$count = $count + 1
}
if($count -gt 0)
{
write-host 'Statistic.FileMonitor:' $count;
write-host "Message.FileMonitor: $count file found and moved, Filenames- $msg"
exit 0
}
else
{
write-host 'Statistic.FileMonitor:' $count;
write-host "Message.FileMonitor: $count files found, Filenames- $msg"
exit 0
}
```

When execution mode is set as Local Host. It execute. But it says no file found. Eventhough file exist under path1

When execution mode is seet as Remote. I am getting result as Down

Comment: Replace `path1` with an absolute path, eg. `C:\path\to\path1`

Comment: Yes, Path1 i just mentioned as a example.

Comment: What logon account is the SAM service running under? Could be that it doesn't have access to read the same directory as the user account you're using to test manually